# I upgraded ubunta 14.04 the video is very slow I installed gnome panel

Tags: 14.04, gnome-panel, gpu-driver

When logging in it did not give me an option to choose anything. Someone please help me. I'm so new at this so make it simple.
I have an Intel integrated gen 2 video